# Why not use otf format in fontawesome to fix chrome bad rendering issue?

Tags: google-chrome, font-awesome

Trying to find a way to get better antialiased rendering of fontawesome icons in chrome in windows i found that using 'otf' format solve the problem.

i used in fontawesome.css:

```
src: url('../font/fontawesome.otf?v=3.1.0') format('opentype'), 
url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), 
url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.1.0') format('woff'), 
url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.1.0') format('truetype'), 
url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.1.0') format('svg');
```

rendering is very good in chrome with a minor issue "in some icons the very top of the icon is cropped", other browsers render the icons clearly without any issue.

my question, why otf version is not used in fontawesome to fix chrome bad rendering issue, the otf file is already present but not included in css?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

I have a problem with icons getting cut off at the top but loading the otf file doesn't fix it.
As chrome can also load svg fonts then the opentype will be downloaded and then overridden with an extra http request for the svg.

So it seems like you are downloading extra data and ending up with the same result?

Comment: Actually otf is not overridden, chrome load otf only & used others as fallback